# Error Drillthrough Action SSAS - Drillthrough failed because the coordinate identified by the SELECT clause

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, data-modeling, olap

A Drillthrough Action was created in SSAS cube with procedure `ASSP.GetCustomDrillthroughMDX` in order to allow users to see further details.

This works fine except for the highlighted cell **99.575 (Fig.1)** . For this cell the following error was retrieved:

> Drillthrough failed because the coordinate identified by the SELECT
>   clause is out of range.

The `drillthorugh` MDX-Query that runs on server is:

```
drillthrough  select (
[Branch].[Branch DE].[All]
,[Branch Hierarchies].[Branch Hierarchy].[7789] --7789
--,[Branch Hierarchies].[PK Branch Hierarchy].[RHO ASL APAC]
,[Cost Category].[Account DE].[All]
,[Date].[Year].&[2016]
,[Documents].[Customer Number].[All]
,[Documents].[Document Currency].[All]
,[Documents].[Document Date].[All]
,[Documents].[Document Header].[All]
,[Documents].[Document Line].[All]
,[Documents].[Document No].[All]
,[Documents].[Document Type].[All]
,[Documents].[Entered By].[All]
,[Documents].[Entry Date].[All]
,[Documents].[Fiscal Period].[All]
,[Documents].[Item Text].[All]
,[Documents].[Partner Business Area].[All]
,[Documents].[Partner Segment].[All]
,[Documents].[Pk Id].[All]
,[Documents].[Reference].[All]
,[Documents].[Storno Doc No].[All]
,[Measures].[Amount]
) on 0 
from [MIS Financials] return 
         NAME([$Date].[Date]) as [Date]
    ,NAME([$Documents].[Document No]) as  [Document No]
    ,NAME([$Documents].[Document Line]) as  [Document Line]
    ,NAME([$Documents].[Document Header]) as  [Document Header]
    ,NAME([$Documents].[Document Date]) as  [Document Date]
    ,NAME([$Documents].[Document Currency]) as  [Document Currency]
    ,NAME([$Documents].[Document Type]) as  [Document Type]
    ,NAME([$Documents].[Entry Date]) as  [Entry Date]
    ,NAME([$Documents].[Entered By]) as  [Entered By]
    ,NAME([$Documents].[Fiscal Period]) as  [Fiscal Period]
    ,NAME([$Documents].[Item Text]) as  [Item Text]
    ,NAME([$Documents].[Reference]) as  [Reference]
    ,NAME([$Documents].[Storno Doc No]) as  [Storno Doc No]
    ,NAME([$Customers].[Customer NO]) as [Customer No]
    ,NAME([$Customers].[Customer Name1]) as [Customer Name 1]
    ,NAME([$Documents].[Partner Business Area]) as [Partner Business Area]
    ,NAME([$Documents].[Partner Segment]) as [Partner Segment]
    ,NAME([$Customers].[Key Industry Sector]) as [Industry Sector Key]
    ,NAME([$Branch].[Branch DE]) as [Branch]
    ,NAME([$Branch].[Branch Number]) as [Branch No]
    ,NAME([$Scenario].[Scenario Type DEU]) as [Scenario Type DEU]
    ,NAME([$Cost Center].[Cost Center DE]) as [Cost Center]
    ,NAME([$Cost Category].[Account No]) as [Cost Category]
    ,[Financials].[Amount] as [Amount]
```

As I made some futher test, I found that the problem with the query it's on line 3: `,[Branch Hierarchies].[Branch Hierarchy].[7789]` . Here, if I change the value `[7789]` with `[ALL]`, the query will run just fine. The value `[7789]` represents the ID of the `RHO ASL APAC` in the parent-child dimension.

*Does anyone knows what cause this error in drillthrough and how could we avoid it?*

**P.S.** The error was also discussed according to this post 
[MDX DRILLTHROUGH Fails but select can be successfully executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194942/mdx-drillthrough-fails-but-select-can-be-successfully-executed) on Stackoverflow. The difference is that in my case I don't use any subselects or multiple members of the same dimension `[Branch Hierarchies]` to cause that .

**Fig.1**

[image: Drillthrough Action]

**UPDATE: Definition of the Drillthrough Action in SSAS**

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that you are requesting a cell that doesn't exist in the cube space? For example, let's say you had a country dimension and you asked for (Country.Country.USA, Country.Continent.Europe). That that row doesn't exist in the Country dimension with that combination of country and continent. Can you craft a drillthrough that tests this theory to see what error you get?

Comment: Can you post the definition of your action? I would like to see the way you call ASSP.

Comment: @GregGalloway I've edited my question with an UPDATE section.

Comment: thanks. Why are you using ASSP here instead of a regular drillthrough action?

Comment: Documents it's the degenerate dimension that will be used only in drillthrough from the end-users

Comment: one of the reason is that, when the EndUser press the normal drillthrough action, in the new excel Sheet , the name of the columns will be something like [$Branch].[Branch Number] instead of Branch Number

Comment: I see. Still may be worth testing to check that normal drillthrough doesn't give the error. Better to have ugly column names than an error.

Comment: @GregGalloway other reason is that you cannot set the ordering of the columns in a normal drillthrough action. For example: Document No before Document Line

Comment: good point. You might be able to edit the XML .cube file and fix this but that's error prone.

Comment: @GregGalloway I tested with the predefined drillthrough action. It's working... it's interesting, it's seems that for the same cell, same coordinates in the cube, ASSP.GetCustomDrillthroughMDX has choosed another path to those coordinates...

Comment: good. So can you use Profiler to see what drillthrough statement is run. Then compare the where clause in that drillthrough to the ASSP generated cell. Maybe there is an ASSP bug. What version are you using? Do you have any default members that aren't All? Any dimension relationships which aren't normal in the dimension usage tab?